# How to add bullet point in a textarea?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to add a bullet point when i click 'enter' button inside textarea. Here is the coding. It did not function at all. Am i wrong?

```
<script>
$(".todolist").focus(function() {
    if(document.getElementById('todolist').value === ''){
        document.getElementById('todolist').value +='• ';
    }
});

$(".todolist").keyup(function(event){
var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
if(keycode == '13')
{
    document.getElementById('todolist').value +='• ';
}
var txtval = document.getElementById('todolist').value;
if(txtval.substr(txtval.length - 1) == '\n')
{
    document.getElementById('todolist').value = txtval.substring(0,txtval.length - 1);
    }
});
</script>


<form>
<textarea id="todolist" class="todolist" name="todolist" rows="10"   placeholder="Maintain your pending tasks"></textarea>
</form>
```

Comment: May be you can use tinyMCE

Comment: it works fine to me~ do you load your javascript after the dom tree

Comment: load javascript after dom tree?what is that?can explain in details?

Comment: Your code is placed before the form, so it is being executed before form is loaded. Place the code below the form or make it work only after the page is loaded.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the code included in the question adding a bullet point inside text area when clicking enter.

Two things that you might need to change:

1) As mentioned by @Alexiy in the comments, the html code needs to come before the javascript code acting on it, unless that javascript is set to run after the document finishes loading.

2) Make sure you are loading jquery on the page before the javascript because you are using jquery within your javascript.

```js
$(".todolist").focus(function() {
  if (document.getElementById('todolist').value === '') {
    document.getElementById('todolist').value += '• ';
  }
});

$(".todolist").keyup(function(event) {
  var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
  if (keycode == '13') {
    document.getElementById('todolist').value += '• ';
  }
  var txtval = document.getElementById('todolist').value;
  if (txtval.substr(txtval.length - 1) == '\n') {
    document.getElementById('todolist').value = txtval.substring(0, txtval.length - 1);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <textarea id="todolist" class="todolist" name="todolist" rows="10" placeholder="Maintain your pending tasks"></textarea>
</form>
```

Comment: How would you modify this code so that if you hit ENTER in the middle of some text in order to send it to the next line and have it start a new bullet, it actually does that instead of breaking the text into a new line at the spot where you hit ENTER but adding the bullet point at the very end of the text block... like in the screenshot here: https://prnt.sc/sfex9w

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned in their comments, the issue with the code you are using is, that you are loading the script BEFORE the browser gets to the HTML code.

One possible overcome is to wrap your entire jQuery code into `$(document).ready()` or one of it's shortened versions.

However, I would recommend not using the `<textarea></textarea>` element for this purpose, but using the unordered list `<ul></ul>`.
To be able to edit it, you can wrap it in a div with `contenteditable` value set to true. So to start off with a single empty bullet, use this HTML (no javascript required!)

```html
<div contenteditable="true">
  <ul>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this.
Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
$('#txt').keyup(function(e){
if(e.keyCode == 13){
var h= $('#txt').val();
$('#txt').val('');
$('#txt').val(h+'*');// put your ascii code for special character
}
});
});
```

html:

```
<textarea id="txt"></textarea>
```